# java 8,List<Employee> to map of department and list of addresses

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I have a class like
    classe User{
        String department;
        String address;
    }
    i have list of user,can i get below output using java 8 stream/map/collect

```
List<User> userList=getUserList();

Map<String,List<String>> userAddressMap=new HashMap<String,List<String>>();

for(User user : userList){

   List<String> addressList=userAddressMap.get(user.getDepartment());

   if(addressList==null){
        userAddressMap.put(user.getDepartment(),addressList);
   }

   addressList.add(user.getAddress);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `groupingBy` collector with `mapping` collector downstream.

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;

Map<String, List<String>> userAddressMap = userList.stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(
        User::getDepartment,
        mapping(User::getAddress, toList())
    ));
```